# How can I display checkbox or radio button choices in a Choice field vertically?

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, list-form, choice-field

I have a list with SharePoint 2007 with a Choice column that I'd like the choices to be displayed vertically (every 2 or 3) instead of horizontally. Is there some JavaScript/jQuery I can utilize to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

SPServices has a method for this:

> The SPArrangeChoices rearranges radio buttons or checkboxes in a form from vertical to horizontal display to save page real estate.

The documentation is here: [SPServices.SPArrangeChoices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPArrangeChoices&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Use it often, great easy way to do it.

Comment: How would I use SPServices within my SharePoint site?

Comment: @wahle509 follow the link, you'll find detailed explanations http://spservices.codeplex.com